# php convert json string to array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json string sent from html...

```
[{"user_id":"test_123"},{"id":"wallName","value":"","type":"text"},{"id":"wallLength","value":"","type":"text"}]
```

I want to retrieve the `"user_id":"test_123"` and then from that create a folder named test_123, maybe even a matching file named test_123. I'm thinking I need to convert the json file to an array, get the `user_id` value and convert that back to a string? Does that make sense or am I over complicating this? I'm new to php so that might very well be the case.

Here's my php code...

```
<?php
   $json=$_POST[json];
   $decodedText=html_entity_decode($json);
   $myArray = json_decode($json, true);

   if (json_decode($json) != null){ 
       $file=fopen('user_data.json','w+');
       fwrite($file, $json);
       fclose($file);

  }else{
      echo "empty";
  }
?>
```

When I try to access `$myArray` it doesn't work.

Comment: json_decode($json)  convert your json to object may be...

Comment: $array =  (array) json_decode($json) ; try this may be it's help you

Comment: @ParthChavda Thanks for the suggestions, how woould I access the array if I want 'test_123'? I'm having a hard time figuring that part out. I would think $array[0] would work but it doesn't seem to

Comment: i have tried your examole it's work when i passed $json = json = '[{"user_id":"test_123"},{"id":"wallName","value":"","type":"text"},{"id":"wallLength","value":"","type":"text"}]';

Comment: https://3v4l.org/T7Y9t

Comment: you can get using $myArray[0]['user_id'];

Comment: @jayxhj thanks that works great!

Comment: @ParthChavda thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get user_id using `$myArray[0]['user_id']`;